# How to redirect user to current page after login (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-3

How do i redirect the user into current page after login?

> User is reading a news at this URL `domain.com/article/news-18565` once he click the login button then how do i get currenturl() before going to `domain.com/login` and after login user should go to `domain.com/article/news-18565`

**Form.html**

```
<form action="signin" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in to your account" class="float-md-right btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Controller.php**

```
    function index(){

    $user_profile = 'user';
    $this->authModel->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($user_profile);

    $rules = $this->authModel->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
        if($this->authModel->login() == TRUE){
            redirect($user_profile);
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'That email/password combination does not exist');
            redirect('signin');
        }
    }
 }
```

**Model.php**

```
    function login(){

    $user = $this->get_by(array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
            'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password'))
        ), TRUE);

    if(count($user)){
        $data = array(
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'username' => $user->username,
            'loggedin' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well you need use HTTP_REFERER url. http Referer url redirect user to last visited url as you say

> E.g: Member is reading a news at this URL domain.com/article/news-18565 once he click the login button then how to get currenturl() before going to domain.com/login and after login member should go to domain.com/article/news-18565

For this you need check the last visited url see in code example.

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else {
   // add here the default url for example dashboard url
}
```

Hope it's help you if you have any question let me know